# how the string variable 'longestString' gets overwritten in this code?

Tags: java, string

I thought that this code will throw an error because the string variable `longestString` gets overwritten every time the loop catches a longer string but it works just fine and the variable gets the new string every time.
can someone explain how?

```
public static String getLongestString(String[] array) {
      int maxLength = 0;
      String longestString = null;
      for (String s : array) {
          if (s.length() > maxLength) {
              maxLength = s.length();
              longestString = s;
          }
      }
      return longestString;
  }
```

Comment: What kind of error were you expecting? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you expect exception because Strings are immutable, right?

`String longestString` (and other String variables) are only references to objects. So `longestString = s` only changes reference to `s` (provided String object from array). Therefore you are not receiving exception because you are not changing String object

This [arcticle](https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool) could clarify it more

Answer (score 0):

What you found is the difference between constant values and variable values.

Variables can be assigned multiple times, they will throw away their previous value and take the new one. You can replace it's contents like a box. Try this:

```java
int x = 10;
x = 23;
x = 99;
System.out.println("x = " + x);
```

On the other side constants can only be assigned once:

```java
final int x = 10;
x = 23; // And stop because this throws an error
```